# Decorator Pattern; Decorating concrete components under two abstract classes

Tags: design-patterns

Edit: I can use Actionscript 3.0 and/or Java

I have a bit of a problem with the decorator class. I want to be able to decorate a subclass of a subclass of the abstract class.

To clarify; I have the `abstract weapon class`, which an `abstract sword class` extends. Then, finally a `concrete long sword class` extends it. I want to be able to decorate the `long sword class`.

```
                                   Weapon <-------------Enchant "Decorator
                                     /\                  /   \
                                    /  \        "+3 damage"|"Paralyze"
                                   /    \                  V
"Abstract Components":       Sword    |    Axe    "Concrete Decorators" 
                              / \         /    \
                             /   \       /      \
"Concrete Components": LongSword|Short RedAxe| WarAxe "Apply Decorators Here"
```

Currently all the books I've read about design patterns deals with "one layer" Decorations, e.g:

```
                                        Weapon <-------------Enchant "Decorator
                                         /\                  /   \
                                        /  \        "+3 damage"|"Paralyze"
                                       /    \                  V
  "Concrete components already":    Sword | Axe      "Concrete Decorators"
```

Comment: Please state the language you are using.

Comment: If it's C# or Java, answer is straightforward, it should work. May be better way to implement enchants is keeping the list of enchantments on weapon instead of decorators? Also, if there's error or unexpected behavior, please provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In static languages like Java, C++ and (I presume) C#, you can't create a decorator for a class and use it to decorate subclasses of that class.  Well you can, but the effect is to hide the functionality of the subclass.

I guess what you want is to be able to mix-and-match decorators, where each decorator could be for the object's class or one of its ancestors.

In the dynamic languages e.g., perl and ruby, you can define or redefine an *individual method* of an individual object, and you could theoretically use this to peform decoration on subclasses.

Assuming you're constrained by a static language, my suggestion is this:  For each kind of enchantment your want to have, create a Modifier base class or interface, and then create concrete classes for each enchantment.  Then in each object, have a list of modifiers of each class/interface, and run through them as necessary to, say, calculate damage.

The closest analogous patterns are Strategy or Template Method.

I have translated your question in my mind to "How would one implement the item modifier system used in the Diablo games?".  There are many issues to consider - saving and restoring state, and  interactions between modifiers, are just two that occur to me now.

Comment: Java/AS3/C++ is okay. I can only 'read' ruby not really program with it. I will test your suggestion. Thank You!

Comment: Yeah Strategy pattern why didn't I think of that! I can only have one enchantment at a time, so I don't need decorators *facepalm* I have never played Diablo, only Starcraft 2. Maybe I should go play that to learn some more mechanics for RPG XD. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class weapon
{
list WeaponDecorator decorators;
hit()
{for each decorator in decorators {
 decorator.hit();}}
}

public abstract class axe : weapon
{hit()}

public class broadaxe : axe
{hit(){
parent.hit();    
implementation;}}

public class WeaponDecorator : weapon
{hit(){
 implement freeze()
}}
```

If I understand your diagram right, this should be an implementation in pseudocode.

Comment: Wow, I think I understand how this works. Definitely going to try it out.

Comment: Also, now I see, that it isn't exactly decorator pattern, but it should work :) Patterns, names are only conventions, in the end